# Multiple IE windows open up for a Watin based exe scheduled through Windows Scheduler

Tags: watin, scheduled-tasks

I have developed an application using watin to test a website. I run the job every 15 minutes, and as long as I was running this with an admin account on the Windows 2008 server, there were no issues.
Recently, I tried changing this to an local computer account(with remote login rights only), and after that every time the scheduler runs the EXE, it opens up 2-3 IE windows instead of the 1 that it is supposed to. I think it is not able to get a handle on any of the windows, and hence the application crashes.

Any ideas if there is some permission related issue here, or what a possible solution could be?

Thanks,
Nirmal

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you have "remote login rights" only, I suspect that you may also need to allow access to run applications. Which could be the problem in this case. Have you tried running any other application whilst logged in remotely?

Also, on the machine where you run the tests, I am assuming using Visual Studio, can you set Visual Studio to run as Admin?

To do this, right click on the VS application icon and you see a Run as Administrator on the compatibility tab.

Btw, running tests in from a remote machine has a few issues. Make sure the server and client don't have auto lock / screensaver turned on.

Let us know how this goes.

Cheers.